# Testing(Ctrl Enter) in adobe flash professional CS6 is extremely slow

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

With dozens of classes, and thousandth of lines code, the testing (Ctrl+Enter) is getting slower and slower.
I have to wait about 3 min each time.
I have a Core 2 due 2ghz
I am not using Libraries
Is this normal? and is there any profiler tool for Flash that can help?

Comment: Dozens of classes and thousands of lines is not much, there should be no problem compiling in a couple seconds. Are there a lot of non-code assets in your project? Also, you're compiling for web, and not mobile, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also a quick fix can be to try turning off "Warnings Mode" in your documents Script settings. 
This can have a massive effect on compile time with big projects.

Comment: Ignoring warnings isn't a great habit to get into. You might end up doing more "damage" (at run time b/c you ignore warnings). I use the word "damage" in quotes as we're only talking about shaving a few milliseconds here and there by fixing compiler warnings.

Comment: From my experience turning a 3 minute compile time down to 15 seconds is a **huge** win for productivity.
Sure you should turn ignore warnings back on periodically to check for those minor things it finds.

Comment: You have a fair point, @adamh I guess its all about finding a balance :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there isn't much that can change this once your code base starts growing.

- You can help prevent it from getting worse by avoiding the importation of unnecessary classes (like using star imports `import flash.display.*;`).
- If possible, break apart your project into smaller projects and then compile them into SWC's. Reference them from your "main" project to link them all together. This will save a lot of time as they have been pre-compiled.
- The above works with vector objects and bitmaps too.
- If you have large amounts of different text families and dynamic text-fields, make sure you only embed the necessary glyphs as these eat up time in compiling too.

Comment: I am using some imports with *, and many embeded TLF texts, will try to fix them. Regarding the SWC, I'm not sure how to do it, is there any specific documentation for it?

Comment: Here is a good article to get you started, http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-guide-to-creating-and-using-swcs--active-1211 and  documentation summarizing the steps involved in exporting SWC's http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001912.html

Comment: How does using a "star import" help? It's no different than if I do an include for some class that is not actually used in my code. Classes that aren't used are not compiled into the SWF period. So unless I'm missing something a star import does nothing, except make things "convenient" for the developer. However, when I come across a new class that I've never seen before, I actually prefer that they **don't** use star imports. Seeing all the classes that are being imported, gives you an idea of the activities that a class might be doing.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't include unused classes in the compiled swf. However many flash  developers have the tendency to import every package in the flash library, even so they may not be used. This combined with numerous classes will increase compile time. This is why I suggest avoiding using star imports unless you are using the entire package.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off "Warnings Mode"

The warnings mode does A LOT of Actionscript 2.0 checking, as my number of lines went into the thousands the compile was just TOO long.

Besides you can always occasionally switch it back on just to see the warnings.